# Call forwarding from device 1 mobile network to device 2 data network

Tags: sms, calls, voip

My brother's new job is underground with no cell reception or 3G. He wants to leave his phone upstairs so it can receive calls and SMS, and somehow forward them to him downstairs to Android / PC / Mac (any of these would be fine) that are connected to the office Wi-Fi.

The upstairs phone may or may not be connected to the same Wi-Fi network; it may just have 3G.

Is there any combination of apps that can do this? And if the request is confusing please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! I'm not 100% sure as I've never tried it (I don't like "network hopping" for privacy reasons), but [Airdroid](http://www.appbrain.com/app/airdroid-android-on-computer/com.sand.airdroid) might be able to do that. Oh, speaking of: Your question is off-topic here ("is there an app for X", see our [help/on-topic]) – and should have been asked on [SR](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) instead :)

Answer (score 0):

[Google Voice](https://www.google.com/voice/) could work, if your brother ported his number to Google Voice (about $20). His cell phone could even be off, yet his computer would be able to receive the calls, since Google Voice can route calls to any numbers associated with its accounts. This method would allow text messages as well.

Alternatively, he could get a brand new Google Voice number, and have his cell carrier forward calls to that number if his cell phone is out of range or goes to voicemail. This would only work for incoming calls, though, not text messages.

Granted, this solution isn't Android-specific, but I'm not sure an app on his phone would be the best solution anyway.